# Objects not registered in the factory when the code is compiled as a library but works fine as stand alone

Tags: c++, singleton, static-libraries, objectfactory

We are trying to transform a code of ours into a library to allow some interfacing with other codes. In the code, we use a lot an object factory relying on the singleton pattern where objects are declared via macros, implemented as hereafter.

Our problem is that when we compile the whole code as a library, objects are not registered anymore in the factory and cannot be created at execution. Would you have any suggestion ? Notably, should something be made extern ? I must confess I reach my limits...

Thanks a lot !

Marc

```
template<typename AClass> class Factory
{
public :

    //! typedef for function creating object by the Factory
    typedef AClass*(*CreateFunc)();

    bool Register(const std::string& id,
          CreateFunc creator)
    {
        return _associations.insert(typename AssocMap::value_type(id, creator)).second;
    }

    bool Unregister(const std::string& id)
    { return _associations.erase(id) == 1; }

    AClass* CreateObject(const std::string& id)
    {

        typename AssocMap::const_iterator i=_associations.find(id);
        if(i!= _associations.end())
            return (i->second)();
        else
            {
                std::cerr << "Unknown Type in object factory : " << id << std::endl;
                exit(-1);
            }
    }

    AClass* CreateObjectIfAvailable(const std::string& id)
    {

        typename AssocMap::const_iterator i=_associations.find(id);
        return (i!= _associations.end() ? (i->second)() : NULL);

    }

    static Factory & Instance()
    {
        static Factory obj;
        return obj;
    }

private:

    //! AssocMap typedef used for map establishing correspondance between CL and std::strings
    typedef std::map<std::string,CreateFunc> AssocMap;

    // Singleton implies creation/destruction entirely private
    Factory():_associations(std::map<std::string,CreateFunc>()) {}

    //! Factory declared private to avoid bad surprises
    Factory(const Factory&);

    //!operator= declared private to avoid bad surprises
    Factory& operator=(const Factory&);

    ~Factory() {}

    //! associations_ contains the correspondance between std::strings and objects
    AssocMap _associations;

};

#define DECLARE_CONSTITUTIVE_LAW(CLASS_NAME,KEYWORD)                    \
    namespace {                             \
    AbstractConstitutiveLaws* creator(){ return new (CLASS_NAME);}  \
    const std::string kwords(KEYWORD);              \
    const bool registered = Factory<AbstractConstitutiveLaws>::Instance().Register(kwords,creator); \
    }
```

Comment: My guess - when linking against a library, the linker only brings over symbols that are actually used by the executable. Object files whose exported symbols are not referenced from anywhere are simply ignored; so `registered` variable is dropped and its initializer doesn't run. Normally, that's a good thing - you wouldn't usually want unused parts of a large library to nevertheless wind up in your binary.

Comment: Hi Igor, thanks for your insight ! But then, would you have any idea of a possible remedy ?

Comment: There might be linker options for force linking an object file. Alternatively, you would have to arrange for the executable to actually mention some symbol from each source file it wants to pull in. Magic self-registration isn't going to work.

Comment: Hi Igor, thanks a lot : that did it ! The linker option is --whole-library, in case it could help someone (using g++).